# User.IsInRole is true in view, but if body isn't shown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a little problem with Razor. It's possible a duplicate, but I didn't find answer.

I use UserIdentity role model and want to change `Index` depend on user's role. I found here the following solution (sorry for my spelling):

```
@if (User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Admin))
{
    Html.ActionLink("Добавить работника", "AddEmploee");
}
```

But when I log in as admin, the helper doesn't generated. The result of `User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Admin)` is true, it goes in if's body but nothing happen on view. I added additional check:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Admin))
```

But result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I was writing this question, I have found solution:

```
@if (User.IsInRole(UserRoles.Admin))
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Добавить работника", "AddEmploee");
}
```

But I will be thankful, if someone explains me, why second '@' is necessary.

Comment: Without the `@`, the method is executed but not output. You need to add it to output the result in the view